# A php Noob in need of some local server help

Tags: php

So i installed XMAPP to view my php site im developing for a php mysql class at my local college and I ran aground hours ago and have been searching frantically for answers since. whenever i try to view my site all i see is this

```
" . $row['tid'] . ""; echo $id; $thisName = "\n
" . $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'] ."
"; echo $thisName; $description = "\n
" . nl2br($row['description']) . "
"; echo $description; echo ""; } include ("footer.php"); ?>
```

or something similar. we host on a local server that has everything we need but cannot access it from our homes. I was wondering if anyone could lend me a hand?

Comment: Did you enclose this in <?php ?> ? I would create a simple echo("asdf"); and make sure your php interpreter is set up correctly.

Comment: I agree, this looks like a problem with php not evaluating your code for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an echo statement where you're using a single quote to open a string but not close it. For instance:

```
echo '" . $row['tid'] . ""; echo $id; $thisName = "
```

Go search in your source for something like this. I'd bet that this is your error.